# Error while loading an STL file using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to show a preview of an STL file using three.js. I followed the following tutorial, because this is exactly what I need:

[Tutorial](http://www.diale.org/javascript3knot.html)

I get an error called `undefined is not a function (near '...loader.addEventListener...')` in the following line:

```
    var loader=new THREE.STLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener('load', function (event){
    var geometry=event.content;
    var material=new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ ambient: 0xFBB917,color: 0xfdd017 });
    var mesh=new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);});
```

I also included all files correctly, what is wrong with my code or is there any alternative for a simple preview of a STL file using javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that tutorial was written with an older version of three.js. For newer versions, when loading STL (and other model formats) you must use a `.load` function:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ ambient: 0xFBB917,color: 0xfdd017 });

var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
loader.load( './models/stl/slotted_disk.stl', function ( geometry ) {
  scene.add( new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ) );
});
```

[STLLoader.js:L18-30](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/loaders/STLLoader.js#L18-L30)